# Can we have a combination of embedding layers and regular layers in a neural network?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to use neural networks for a binary classification problem using Keras. I am new to the whole neural network area. What I like to do is to have a network that has embedding layer for some features but regular input layer for the other features. For example, imagine I would like to use user ID as the input that goes to the embedding layer and everything else goes to the regular input layer. I know my question is more conceptual than technical so I am asking if this is possible to do in Keras or any other framework or tools for implementing neural networks.

Comment: I answered but be advised that this is not strictly speaking a programming question so it's off topic, and it's hard to be more precise without you giving more info and a minimal working piece of code

Answer (score 2):

Yes its possible, you have to use functioal API

Here is example,  feel free to adapt for your needs:

```
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Concatenate, Reshape, Input, Dropout, Dense, BatchNormalization, Activation, concatenate 
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding

extraInput = Input((116,))
embed_input = Input((1,)) 

em_model = Embedding(10, 
                     5,
                    input_length=1, 
                    embeddings_initializer='uniform')(embed_input)

em_model = Reshape((5,))(em_model)
outputs = Concatenate(axis=1)([em_model,extraInput])

outputs = BatchNormalization(epsilon=1e-05, momentum=0.1) (outputs)

outputs = Dense(10, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu')(outputs)
outputs = Dense(3, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu')(outputs)
outputs = Dense(1)(outputs)
outputs = Activation('sigmoid')(outputs)

model = Model([embed_input, extraInput], outputs)
model.summary()
```

this will give you following graph: where you have two different inputs one for embedding and second for continues variable

[image]

Comment: What is a usecase for this architecture ?

Comment: Good question. Imagine you have 2 columns. 1 is categorical and 1 is continue. Suppose you want to do embedding for categorical variable and combine with continue variable later for feeding in to NN. This architecture achieve this. Input 6 layer accepts inputs (categorical with 10 unique categories) and embed them in to the vector which has dimension 5. This embedding vector gets combined with continue input at layer 5. Hope it helps.

Comment: Could you cite a real-world example ?

Comment: sure https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.06737, https://github.com/entron/entity-embedding-rossmann

Comment: @H.Bukhari Thanks. How did you choose 10 and 5 as the parameters in your embedding later?

Comment: @H.Bukhari Also since you concatenated embedding and input layer, how are the embedding values going to be updated during the training?

Comment: regarding numbers 10 and 5. This was just an example I assumed that 10 is total number of unique values in the column, I am embedding it to 5 dimensional vector. There is no golden rule on how to chose the embedding number many people prefer to divide number of unique values by 2, but you can also make more smaller lets 3. Here is another example If your column containn 150 unique values you can embed it in to 50 or 30.

Comment: The weights of embedding layers are updates in a same manner as for normal backprog. There is nothing different.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. In any framework.

---

Basically, in such an architecture you'd have two neural components:

- a **feature extractor** which would look at the raw data and produce an output, with the dimensionality of your choice
- a **classifier** which would take features as inputs (features from your feature extractor, concatenated with your own engineered features) and produce a classification distribution